# how to download and install git client for window using Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I have to write automated powershell script for cloning repository from gihtub but I need to install git using command line.Could you please let me know how can I download and install git on window  using command line without doing any  manual work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you wont.. in windows you can do it by installing from exe not from command line..

Answer (score 27):

Was looking to do the same without using chocolatey. The following is working for me, using powershell to download and install the 64-bit version of git-for-windows:

```
# get latest download url for git-for-windows 64-bit exe
$git_url = "https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest"
$asset = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $git_url | % assets | where name -like "*64-bit.exe"
# download installer
$installer = "$env:temp\$($asset.name)"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $asset.browser_download_url -OutFile $installer
# run installer
$git_install_inf = "<install inf file>"
$install_args = "/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOADINF=""$git_install_inf"""
Start-Process -FilePath $installer -ArgumentList $install_args -Wait
```

Where `<install inf file>` is the path to a file that contains install parameters for the git installation. As an example, this is the one I'm using (which I obtained by running through the git installer exe once with the `/SAVEINF=<install inf file>` parameter):

```
[Setup]
Lang=default
Dir=C:\Program Files\Git
Group=Git
NoIcons=0
SetupType=default
Components=ext,ext\shellhere,ext\guihere,gitlfs,assoc,autoupdate
Tasks=
EditorOption=VIM
CustomEditorPath=
PathOption=Cmd
SSHOption=OpenSSH
TortoiseOption=false
CURLOption=WinSSL
CRLFOption=LFOnly
BashTerminalOption=ConHost
PerformanceTweaksFSCache=Enabled
UseCredentialManager=Enabled
EnableSymlinks=Disabled
EnableBuiltinInteractiveAdd=Disabled
```

Learned about the install parameter file from this answer to a similar question: https://superuser.com/a/1005634/1104046.

Running this will require a restart of the shell in order to update the Path environment variable and have git commands work. Alternatively, you could update the current powershell Path environment variable with

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

which will then include the path to git.exe in the Path variable.

Comment: In case you want a simpler version (without the latest parsing): 

`Invoke-Webrequest 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.42.0.windows.2/Git-2.42.0.2-64-bit.exe' -OutFile 'Git-2.42.0.2-64-bit.exe'; ./Git-2.42.0.2-64-bit.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS` and hereafter run env. path 'hack': 
`$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")`

This works for me - and I can manually adjust the latest version.

Answer (score 18):

You can script installation of Git using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

The package is documented at https://chocolatey.org/packages/git

1. First you must [install chocolatey, but that can be done on the command line](https://chocolatey.org/install).
2. Then the command is:

> choco install -y git

Comment: Thank You so much :) It really helped.

Comment: I have successfully installed git but once i try to check git --version and   I am exception  **" git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
"**

Comment: @PriyaRani that sounds like git is not on the PATH after all. Did it look like the installation command was successful?

Comment: Yes... **Chocolatey v0.10.8
Installing the following packages:
git
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

git v2.14.2.20170927 [Approved]
git package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
 The install of git was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or 
  default install location if installer.**

Comment: It installed successfully but I am not able to get path . I checked

Comment: Can you execute `& 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe' --version`?

Comment: NO, Git is not available in this path...Same error getting

Comment: @PriyaRani then the installation seems not to have succeeded. Run it again?

Comment: FOR THOSE HERE IN THE COMMENTS WITH THE "" git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a..." error, Please ensure that you restart your shell after installation and then run the git commands.

Comment: I faced the same issue as @Priya Rani, apparently, I only had to restart my PowerShell

Comment: Guys, there's even a warning in the installer `WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell before you can use choco.` It's pretty standard to have to restart your shell when **anything** adds something to your PATH variable

Answer (score 16):

Just one command solution
Open Powershell and type the command:
`winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget`
Restart the powershell and you will have Git in command line.

Comment: This should be the correct solution. Nothing else to install, clean and simple

Comment: Note that this is not available on clean WIndows Server instances, whereas tdashroy's answer works

Comment: @dataprincess is absolutely right. This solution can't work for windows servers as winget isn't available from start.

Answer (score 1):

To installation via a Dockerfile in CI

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Assuming that you have "install-git-instructions.txt" file in the directory where this Dockerfile is located

ADD install-git-instructions.txt .

RUN powershell.exe -Command \
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
  (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.39.0.windows.1/Git-2.39.0-64-bit.exe','c:\Git-2.39.0-64-bit.exe') ; \
  Start-Process c:\Git-2.39.0-64-bit.exe -ArgumentList '/LOADINF=""C:\install-git-instructions.txt"" /SILENT' -Wait ;\
  Remove-Item c:\Git-2.39.0-64-bit.exe -Force;\


# Example Contents for install-git-instructions.txt 
#[Setup]
#Lang=default
#Dir=C:\Program Files\Git
#Group=Git
#NoIcons=0
#SetupType=default
#Components=gitlfs
#Tasks=
#PathOption=Cmd
#SSHOption=OpenSSH
#CURLOption=OpenSSL
#CRLFOption=CRLFAlways
#BashTerminalOption=MinTTY
#PerformanceTweaksFSCache=Enabled
#UseCredentialManager=Disabled
#EnableSymlinks=Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Using winget tool
Install [winget tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) if you don't already have it, then type this command in command prompt or Powershell.

```
winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget
```