# Unable to install Git Extensions silently using Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, silent-installer

I am new to Powershell commands. I was trying to write a code to install Git extensions silently but with no success. Can I get a write way to do this.

I am trying some code like this:

```
***$installerFilename = ".\Git-" + $versionToInstall + "-64-bit.exe"
$installer = Resolve-Path $installerFilename
Write-Host "Running Git installer:" $installer
$optionsFile = Resolve-Path ".\install-defaults.txt"
$logFile = $env:TEMP + "\Git-install-" + $timestamp + ".log"
$commandLineOptions = '/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /FORCECLOSEAPPLICATIONS /LOADINF="'+ $optionsFile + '" /LOG="' + $logFile + '"'
Write-Host "With options:" $commandLineOptions
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $installer -ArgumentList $commandLineOptions
## Configure git with some defaults
### Set git as a command alias
if (!(Test-Path -Path "alias:git")) 
{
   new-item -path alias:git -value 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe'
}
### Invoke git commands that set defaults for user.
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git config --global push.default simple
git config --global core.autocrlf true***

*Write-Host "Git installer done."*
```

I am trying to replace with the path of installation file in my system. This did not give any error but its not working either.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, when running external stuff form PowerShell, quoting is a vital part of the params implementation. [There are blogs/articles/docs on the topic.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20running%20exe%27%20arguments&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20running%20exe%27%20argument&sc=1-33&sk=&cvid=55898CB70F3C4D05B44A8C9D5BEDD05B)

I've not had a need to do this Git thing silently, but see if either of these provides any edification.

> [how to download and install git client for window using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731433/how-to-download-and-install-git-client-for-window-using-powershell)

```
# run installer
$git_install_inf = "<install inf file>"
$install_args = "/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOADINF=""$git_install_inf"""
Start-Process -FilePath $installer -ArgumentList $install_args -Wait
```

> [git-powershell-silent-install/git-silent-uninstall.ps1](https://github.com/Limech/git-powershell-silent-install)

I tweaked what you posted a bit, because of the quoting thing, and tried to potentially deal with maybe, just maybe, that was that catch22 for your use case.

Point of note:

These changes are untested since I already have Git installed and set up as I need it to be, I did not want to mess with my environment for validation.

I tweaked what you posted a bit, because of the quoting thing...

> [about_Quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)
>
> [PowerShell Quoting](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)

...and tried to potentially deal with maybe, just maybe, that was that catch22 for your use case. Also, I yanked the Write-Host stuff, since output to the screen is the PowerShell default. Well, that and historically Write-Host just not recommended [(even by the father of Monad/PowerShell)](http://www.jsnover.com) [vs Write-Output](https://www.bing.com/search?q=write-Host%20vs%20Write-Output&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=write-host%20vs%20write-outpu&sc=5-25&sk=&cvid=AEA209A6CC4644ECBC96852D26CA0C60) prior to PowerShell v5.

Sources:

> [Write-Host considered harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful)
>
> [With PowerShell v5 Write-Host no longer "kills puppies"](https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208)
>
> [Write-Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1)

*Point of note:*

*These changes are untested since I already have Git installed and set up as I need it to be, I did not want to mess with my environment for validation.*

```
$installerFilename = ".\Git-$($versionToInstall)-64-bit.exe"
$installer = Resolve-Path $installerFilename

"Running Git installer:  $installer"

$optionsFile = Resolve-Path '.\install-defaults.txt'
$logFile = "$env:TEMP\Git-install-$($timestamp).log"

$commandLineOptions = "/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /FORCECLOSEAPPLICATIONS /LOADINF=' $optionsFile  /LOG=  $logFile'"

"With options: $commandLineOptions"

<#
Use this option 

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $installer -ArgumentList $commandLineOptions

or 

PowerShell.exe -Command "& $installer $commandLineOptions"
#>

## Configure git with some defaults
### Set git as a command alias
if (!(Test-Path -Path 'alias:git')) 
{New-Item -path 'alias:git' -value 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe'}

### Invoke git commands that set defaults for user.
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git config --global push.default simple
git config --global core.autocrlf true***

'Git installer done.'
```